# Bridge cameras and connect to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge, ip-camera, cctv

I'm hoping to connect two H.264 cameras (with ethernet ports) to the main LAN wirelessly. Can a cheap switch be used and somehow have it connected to the LAN via WiFi? Perhaps a wireless bridge? But I read that WiFi isn't designed for bridging. Does anyone know of a good way to connect to the LAN via WiFi?

Comment: Yes, it’s called exactly that. A “Wireless Bridge.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for dd-wrt/openwrt compatible routers on your favorite online retailer, or you may even have an old router that might work. (Check the hardware compatibility lists on either firmwares respective websites).

Either firmware will allow you to use the wireless radio in "client" or "bridge mode" essentially turning the router and four port switch to a "Ethernet to wireless adapter".

If you need help setting it up, use your favorite search engine looking for wireless client setup & using the name of whatever firmware you wound up choosing.

Or you could come back and ask about the setup steps as it's own question.

Edit:
Use WDS modes if you are worried about Mac limitations that **may or may not** be in the newer versions of ddwrt. WDS modes totally overcome the limitations listed here: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge#Limitations

In the case of using WDS, both ends of the link would need to be dd-wrt/openwrt devices, preferably with the same build number of software to ensure both devices have the same WDS compatibility.
~regards

Comment: I read that because each side has only one MAC, WiFi bridging isn't a good idea - am I right?

Comment: If you have a compatible Android, wifi analyzer from the play store works pretty well.

Comment: According to [ddwrt](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge) "Client Bridge mode will only recognize one mac address on the bridged setup, due a limitation in the 802.11 protocol, even if there are multiple clients (with multiple mac addresses) connected to the client router... It may cause ARP table problems, if you connect more than one computer on the far end of a Client Bridge mode setup." Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated your answer, To be clear, I have used both client(NATed) and client-bridge(bridged segment) and have never had protocol or connection issues past the client device. I have some devices here that I can set up and test, because I'm now curious with the newer versions. I will probably be back to update this answer with the results. ~regards

Comment: Interesting. I look forward to your update!